# How to secure Apache mod_info but keep remote access

Tags: security, apache-2.4

I use [Apache's `mod_info`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_info.html) to display detailed information about my server setup.

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
# Set path below to be handled by mod_info. It will show server info. 
# For this to work, this module must be loaded (uncommented in httpd.conf)
<Location /special/path>
   SetHandler server-info
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

`Allow from` is set to the local machine because this is on my dev machine.

This module allows me to see a tremendous amount of information by navigating to `/special/path`.  I'd like to use it on my public server but need to secure it somehow so others cannot load that path.

The docs discuss whitelisting by IP address but I have an organizational IP, shared by many.

What's the most practical way to protect this path?
`Apache 2.4.16`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not limited to setting IP access controls, you can also use any other access control that is allowed in a `<Location>` scope, or combination thereof. So use the `RequireAll` directive to require both a specific IP-address and set up authentication and require a specific login.

```
<Location /special/path>
  SetHandler server-info
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted Access To Special Location"
  AuthBasicProvider file
  AuthUserFile "/usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords"
  <RequireAll>
    Require ip 10.252.46.165
    Require user BeetleJuice   
  </RequireAll>
</Location>
```

Comment: If you can, please elaborate just a bit.  (1) how will server know that BeetleJuice is connecting and how will it check/verify password? (2) Where does this directive go relative to `<Location>`? Is it a child node (ie. within the `location` tags).

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html

Comment: Thank you. Will study that document later in the day and try to apply it.

Answer (score 2):

Set it to only be available on 127.0.0.1, and then access it via an ssh tunnel.

Comment: I can access webpage via SSH tunnel?  Would you show one example please? And does that mean SSH connection doesn't see my remote IP?  I ask because in the logs I can see the IP I"m connecting to SSH from